# How to extract identical columns between a pandas dataframe and a sparse matrix

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, scikit-learn, nltk

I currently have a small training set of tf-idf features (about 250 columns of individual words) that I hand labeled as 1's and 0's manually. The training set is small largely because it would take a long time to label more data and I want to see how well the model can do with this small training set. Because the data is small I created features with tf-idf and converted it into a pandas dataframe. So a minimal example to get a better idea of what I am talking about, let's say in training I only have:

```
              Hello great car    target variable
great car        0   .35 .25            1 
Hello great car  .40   .15 .10          0
```

Now, I did exactly the same thing with the test set. However, the test set is huge compared to the training set

```
            car great plane boring yoo nice dude man jump fancy japan target
car japan  .53  0     0     0      0   0    0    0   0    0      .60   1
man car yoo .53 0     0     0      .30 0    0    .15 0    0        0   0
jump        0   0     0     0      0   0    0    0   .45  0        0   1
```

In reality this testing set above is many thousand times larger from the number of rows compared to the training set and hence, due to this, it has waaay more features in it (words that I tf-idfed). Now, because this is so, I have only been able to get it tf-idf into a sparse matrix and not into a pandas dataframe so the output currently shows:

```
<1383329x27870 sprase matrix fo type ',class 'numpy.float'>' with 15874611 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

My only question is, in order to .fit() and .predict() a machine learning model needs an equal number of input x features in it's training and testing set so what I want to do is get rid of all the features in the test set (there's a ton) that are not in the training set however I was not sure how to do that with comparing a sparse matrix and a pandas dataframe? Typically, when I compare pandas dataframes, I just do a x['y'].isin[a['b']] and filter out all the columns that are common to both. Not sure how to do the same thing when comparing a pandas dataframe and sparse matrix?

Comment: Why does your test set *have more features to begin with*? You should be featurizing it with the same `TfidfVectorizer` object, after *that* has been trained on the test set. IOW, you split the *raw documents* into a training and testing set. You then fit your vectorizer with the training set, and transform both the training and testing set using this fit. **Then** you use these (equivalently featurized) sets of data with the actual model.

Comment: so do I understand correctly that what the transform method does it essentially do what I am wanting it to do, it gets rid of the extra columns?

Comment: No, it *never creates the columns in the first place*. Again, you generally never want to "remove columns" unless you are doing *feature selection*. But even then, using a Tfidf language model, you shouldn't be doing that by just dropping columns, but by fitting your *vectorizer* on a smaller subset of the *vocabulary*.

Comment: How exactly does the .transform method achieve from a machine learning point of view?

Comment: It essentially does what is described [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_extraction.html#tfidf-term-weighting). You could do it by hand pretty easily. In fact, you should probably read that whole section titled Bag-of-Words in the feature-extraction tutorial.

Comment: this explains what tf-idf does it seems like, but what does the .transform() that you mention do in this case is what I am trying to understand

Comment: ... I have no idea how that doesn't answer your question. That is what the `.transform` method does. The `.fit` method essentially gathers the "global" counts, then the `.transform` method applies the tf-idf transformation on the individual documents. Haven't you been using this the whole time? And [here's the source code for the transformer](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/7389dba/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py#L1137) which is will tell you exaxtly what is going on

Comment: so if my code is for training: Counter = Training['Text'].values.tolist() vec = TfiDfVectorizer() X=vec.fit_transform() and I have the same code for the testing set, which part is wrong and how does it need to get fixed?

Comment: That code doesn't make any sense. What are you doing with `Counter`? You donn't pass anything to `fit_transform`, so that would probably error (or maybe X would just be empty). What is `Training`??? In any event, assuming the code does make sense,  you shouldn't be*training* on your *testing set*, that is what is fundamentally wrong. You just transform the testing set with the vectorizer your trained on your training set.

Comment: ok I guess now I am just getting confused. Let's say we have DataFrame A as Training A['y'] is the target label and we have DataFrame B as the testing set with B['y'] as the target variable. What would your code look like to do tfidf here and do a train/predict with some given ML model?

Comment: What is in your dataframe? Dude, this is all elementary stuff, and I can't just sit here and explain this all to you in the comments section. I would suggest going through some tutorials on these things, or taking a free class on coursera or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look, here's a *sketch* of how you would do what you are trying to do:

```
documents = [
    'the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog',
    'the name of the game is pain',
    'what is in a name? Is a rose as sweet by any other name',
    'the world is a world of many people',
    'i am running out of things to write',
    'yeah now I am totally out of things to write'
]

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

# train test splitting, of course, you wouldn't do it this way...
import random
random.shuffle(documents)
train, test = documents[:len(documents)//2], documents[len(documents)//2:]


vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
Xtrain = vectorizer.fit_transform(train)
Xtest = vectorizer.transform(test)
```

Of course, this is not how you would actually do a train-test split /  cross validation. There's all sorts of ways to approach it, here's just [one of many guides](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html#cross-validation-evaluating-estimator-performance) on the subject.

Ok now, you would do something like:

```
from sklearn.fancy_model import FancyModel

model = FancyModel(param=42).fit(Xtrain, Ytrain) # assuming you have your labels
yhat_train = model.predict(Xtrain)
yhat_test = model.predict(Xtest)

# compare your metric based on yhat_train and yhat_test....
```

Comment: Thank you, that seems to make it work. Question, what does model.transform() does in the last 2 lines of the code? y_hat_train and yhat_test? What will happen differently if you don't do these?

Comment: @mkheifetz that was a mistake, it should have been `.predict`